# Git workflow for my case

Tags: git

Have following remote branches

1. master - deployment
2. staging - testing

3 developers are working on 3 different features

Developer 1 - feature 1
Developer 2 - feature 2
Developer 3 - feature 3

feature 3 gets completed first , dev3 pushes it to staging.
When feature 1 gets completed second  , dev1 pushes it to staging.
When feature 2 gets completed last  , dev2 pushes it to staging.

now the staging repo has the following commit history

feature 3
feature 1
feature 2

Testers pass only feature 1 and feature 3 and 2 has some bugs to fix.
I want to release feature 1 .

In this case, I cannot merge staging into master.

I am left with Cherry-pick only.
But Cherry-pick should not be used always as a best practice.

what will be the suited git workflow for this type of scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to create a new staging branch with feature 2 in it (temporary), since you'll need to retest without features 1 and 3 anyway in case there are any dependencies or bugs in 2 hidden by the presence of 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks Douglas.In my case, all the 3 features have to be tested at the same time. what would be the best workflow ?

Comment: 1. I mean that you need another test pass with just feature 2 to ensure it works without features 1 & 3.

Comment: I'm unclear about "have to" in your comment: Either "have to" means software interconnection in which case you don't really have 3 features, or time pressure in which case you've lost already.

Comment: they may or may not be interconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Since git takes snapshots not file changes, you would have to identify the files in feature 2 and 3, remove them, create a new commit with only files with feature 1, commit, the work flow would remain the same.